# kivy threading not working with me (app not responding)

Tags: python, kivy, python-multithreading, kivy-language

Hello guys I have a problem with my kivy app when i start to run some functions the app stop responding i tried to solve it by using threading but its not working with.

so this is widget class :

```py
class PyWidget(Widget):
  stop = threading.Event()

  def start_thread(self): 
    self.ids.mic.source = 'assets/open2.png'
    self.ids.mic.reload()
    time.sleep(1)
    threading.Thread(target=self.start_listening).start();

    
  @mainthread
  def start_listening(self):
    while True:
      try:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Listening.......')
        voiceText = RecognizeVoice()
        # time.sleep(1)
        if 'hello' in voiceText and Talking(App, respone, RecognizeVoice):
          return
        
        # else: Talking(App, respone, RecognizeVoice)
        time.sleep(1)
      except Exception as e:
        print(f'start_listening: {e}')
```

`RecognizeVoice` function to start the mic and get user voice to text

```py
def RecognizeVoice():
  try:
    with speechRec.Microphone() as sound:
      voice = recognizer.listen(sound)
      voiceText = recognizer.recognize_google(voice, language="en-US") #online 
      voiceText = voiceText.lower()
      print(f'Input : {voiceText}')
      return voiceText
  except speechRec.UnknownValueError as e:
    print(f'RecognizeVoice: {e}')
  except speechRec.RequestError as e:
    print(f'RecognizeVoice: {e}')
    respone('Sorry, something went wrong.')
```

```py
# Text to speech
def respone(message):
  AI.say(message)
  AI.runAndWait()
```

in my GUI i have a button that when i click the `start_thread` function starts and all others follow it, i hope that i explained everything. thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

The `@mainthread` decorator on the `start_listening()` method defeats the `threading`. Just remove that decorator.